# URL Rewrite rule not working on nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I want to make a url rewrite like in apache within nginx. Basically to give location based request a more url friendly look. I keep getting 404 page not found.

```
server {

  # site definitions (...)

  # fastcgi defitions (...)

  location / {

    # Code to make wp super cache work (...)

    rewrite ^/ads/category/(.*)/(.*)$ /ads/category/$1?location=$2 permanent;
    rewrite ^/category/(.*)/(.*)$ /ads/category/$1?location=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/category/(.*)$ /ads/category/$1 last;

  }
}
```

I'm putting the above code within the virtual host definition /etc/nginx/sites-enable/mysite. So far I dont know a real method to debug what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining all rewrite rules in single location / {} block; try something like this:

```
# site definitions (...)

location / {
    # Code to make wp super cache work (...)

    # remove following line if you already have an index at site definitions..
    index index.php;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  if (!-f $request_filename) {
       rewrite ^/ads/category/(.*)/(.*)$ /ads/category/$1?location=$2 permanent;
       rewrite ^/category/(.*)/(.*)$ /ads/category/$1?location=$2 break;
       rewrite ^/category/(.*)$ /ads/category/$1 break;
  }

 # fastcgi defitions (...)
```

i know [if is evil](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil) in nginx world but its problematic when used in location {} block also similar configuration working like a charm on my virtual server.